# How can I prevent opening multiple browser windows with deep links in PWA?

Tags: url, browser, nfc, qr-code, progressive-web-apps

Is it possible to make sure that (deep) links don't open a new browser window? 
Use case would be e.g. QR Codes or NFC tags that contain some kind of identifier along with a URL/deep link URL.
e.g. www.example.com/mypwa/game=ID

The idea in this case would be that an asset linked to ID would become available in the app.

When you want to do that repeatedly, currently both Chrome on Android and Safari on iOS (as Standard Browser) open a new tab for each tapped NFC tag, confusing the user.

Is it possible for a PWA to check if it is already running in another tab, and if yes, take over the URL parameter (ID) and work with it ?

Comment: Have you checked this related [open issue](https://github.com/w3c/manifest/issues/363) in github?

Comment: Honestly I don't get how it is related - and it is also anyway open, so doesn't offer a solution ...